# Blender 2.8 - Is there a way to retrace or resample the whole scene?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I am a game programmer engaging in 3D art as a hobby. I recently started using Blender 2.8 but I noticed that whenever I make changes to nodes of a material, it doesn't update it in the 3D viewport until I close and reopen Blender and then my updates appear.
Am I supposed to click something to update the material whenever I make changes to the node?

If this issue sounds strange I can upload a video to show it.

Comment: I want to add that the viewport updates when I paint on a texture already linked in the material. But if I add a new texture or node ... or even remove an existing node it doesn't update that.

Comment: This seems like a bug, and you should probably report it to the tracker with video, system specs, video driver version etc (https://developer.blender.org/). The viewport definitely should update.

Comment: Not just the viewport. Even the material tab in the properties window doesn't update the material in its preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on a Mac? This is a bug in the current MacOS build of Blender 2.8:

https://developer.blender.org/T61641[1](https://developer.blender.org/T61641)

A workaround is to make another change and then undo it by pressing ctrl+z

Comment: Wow! You are totally right. Thanks for this. It helps a lot, and I hope it helps other people too.

Comment: In the newest release it's already fixed.

Comment: That's great to hear